# How to create job based on query execution

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two stored procedures where I need to create job based on query execution.
Means first I need to execute a statement based on the result, then I need to execute the stored procedures. And I wish to schedule this job every day.

Comment: If it is ASYNC, you can save query result to table, and have the SP read the data from the table. If it's a sync process, should be easier to manipulate the result set data.

Comment: So what is your specific question? Are you looking for examples of how to create a agent job programmatically (which seems strange since that is usually a one-time action)? Or do you just want to schedule or start an existing job? What edition of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a trigger, its execution body is your 'schedule'. And it is executed when time indicate 00:00:00(means everyday) by timer.